# How to link between make program with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I wanted to ask I have the make program sensor from A111 pulsed radar sensor from sparkfun. https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-a111-pulsed-radar-sensor/all#get-the-sdk

From the program how can I link with ROS. I'm using ROS noetic, raspberry pi debian buster 32 bit. Is there anyone can teach and help me with this since I don't have experienced in ROS. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392764/how-to-link-between-make-program-with-ros/) by [Nur92](https://answers.ros.org/users/88172/nur92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to work through a few first tutorials [there](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) (up to ROS "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)" will be enough) and then use example program from Sparkfun with reading sensors from A111 - you should try to modify and implement publishing appropriate type of [ROS msg](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/tree/noetic-devel/sensor_msgs) or a custom one for your needs.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2021-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1